# I can't see FCM notification messages report

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

We send notification message via HTTP API and I can see `notification_receive` report with Firebase console. Then I follow this [guide](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268). Linked our Firebase account with our Google Developer account.

I can see the registration data, but no push messages data. How can I track the message status with Firebase Analytics or Google Play Developer console? Is there anyone that has the same situation?

Registration data:

[image: registration data]

[no messages data][3]

update----------------
when i send notification via http api and i get logs from device below:

> D/FirebaseMessaging: Showing notification

and when i send notification via firebase console then i get logs from my device below:

> D/FirebaseMessaging: Sending event=_nr params=Bundle[{_ndt=0, _nmt=1484297461, _nmid=2296940352941409747}]
>
> D/FirebaseMessaging: Showing notification

i want to know than can i add some parameter to api for my device sending events ? i try to find the difference between the tow ways from firebase source, but it is not open source

Comment: Hi. Is your app already published?

Comment: yes,and we have 300 million persons to register,and i can see the report from upon image i upload

Comment: hi,@AL.do you know how to send notification via api and get the notification_receive report like sending notification via firebase console?

Comment: Analytics for FCM is only available via the console right now. If you want to register events for notifications that you send from the HTTP API then you will have to register those yourself.